# Draw PdfSharp chart on PictureBox

Tags: c#, charts, picturebox, pdfsharp

Is there a way to draw PdfSharp Chart on PictureBox rather then to pdf?

```
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
    PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();
    page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;
    XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.Bold);
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

    Chart chart = LineChart();
    ChartFrame chartFrame = new ChartFrame();
    chartFrame.Location = new XPoint(30, 30);
    chartFrame.Size = new XSize(500, 200);
    chartFrame.Add(chart);
    chartFrame.Draw(gfx);
```

That gives my nice chart that I can save as pdf. `LineChart()` is just creating a simple chart.

I need to draw this chart over `PictureBox` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PDFsharp, you can try the following:

You can use method `Graphics.FromImage` to get a Graphics object for an Image.
You can use method `XGraphics.FromGraphics` to get an XGraphics object for that Graphics object.
This should allow the chart to draw directly on the Image instead of creating a PDF file.

The PictureBox should be able to display the Image.

Just theory - I didn't try it myself.